# Azure Traffic Manager and DDoS attacks

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

So I have my website set up, call it www.mywebsite.com.  I have my Traffic Manager set up so that www.mywebsite.com points to mytrafficmanager.trafficmanager.com.

The Traffic Manager then points to my two on-premise web front-ends web1.mywebsite.com and web2.mywebsite.com.  It also has an endpoint of a Azure Web App.

It is set up to do a Priority fail over: web1, then if that fails to web2, and if they are both down, to fail over to the Azure Web App.

My question is this: If I get a DDoS attack on www.mywebsite.com, what would happen?  Would the on-premise servers go down, and then it would fail over to the Azure Web App (which is set up to scale appropriately to hopefully mitigate a DDoS attack).  Or would it not be able to route the traffic properly?

Comment: Would you please explain the downvote?  Is it off-topic, or is more information required?

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN forum topic for answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92733178-f305-4994-b954-67da945f40a7/azure-traffic-manager-and-ddos-attacks?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork